# css element dissapears behind padding border

Tags: html, css, padding

I need your help.

The Title in the green Box "News" appears right under this Link.
http://www.mjart.ch/category/news/

But because of this weird Template I'm using, there are sometimes some imperfections. On this Site here
http://www.mjart.ch/portfolio/
the Green title seems to disappear behind the padding border. I really don't know why.

What I found out is that there are 2 different CSS styles. The first one that works is a `.blog-title` and the second one is a `.single-title`. But both are same styled. I would be happy about some help.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce that problem. Which browser/version are you using? Is it possible to include a screen-shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: If you mean that the title "Portfolio" has some space beside it, whereas "News" does not, it's because of the class `.grid_12`, which has `margin:0 25px;` applied to it. It's showing up on your portfolio page because the structure (in how you nest you elements) is a bit different. You'll either need to change your structure on the Portfolio page to match that of the News page, or you'll need to compensate for that 25px margin with something like a negative margin somewhere. Let me know if you need clarification, or if I should write a suggested solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you dont want to change the structure of the template you can add this css rules

```
.page-id-21 .single-page{
    margin:0;
}
.page-id-21 .single-page .single-content{
    margin-left: 25px;       
}
```

I added a     .page-id-21 class, otherwise in the contact page you will add a margin.
This can be a solution, another is to search the correct template page, if it's a premium plugin it will have it, and you dont need to add the css rules.